# Check if cookie doesnot exists and show a pop-up

Tags: jquery, django, cookies

Hi I am trying to show a pop-up/modal to unregistered user (hence that user.is_authenticated thing below) if cookie is not found, i am using jquery plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), with this code, (i am working with django)
in simpler words, i want to check if the cookie with name second_page does not exists or has expired,upon which i can show modal box and create the cookie at the same time.

```
$(function(){
if ('{{user.is_authenticated}}' == 'False'){
    if ($.cookie('second_page')===null){
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
        var expDate = new Date(); 
        expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (60*6*1000)); 
        $.cookie("second_page", 1, { expires: expDate });
    }
}
```

});

but this doesn works ? What i am doing wrong here ? all help appreciated :)

Comment: Start by console logging `$.cookie('second_page')` and see what you get

Comment: how can we do this i.e check if a cookie exists and if not show the pop-up and create the cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

To read back the value of the cookie:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("second_page");
```

To check if value is undefined then check for typeof

```
if( typeof $.cookie("second_page") != 'undefined') {

}
```

Comment: what if i get the cookie value as undefined, how can i use this value in if condition ?

Comment: if you getting as undefined value then if( typeof $.cookie("second_page") == 'undefined')

Comment: it still doen solves my problem .. i did this:$(function(){
if ('{{user.is_authenticated}}' == 'False'){
 var cookie_val = $.cookie('second_page')
 if ( typeof ($.cookie("second_page")) == 'undefined'){
  $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
  var expDate = new Date(); 
  expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (60*6*1000)); 
  $.cookie("second_page", 1, { expires: expDate });
 }
}
}); and now i am creating cookie second_page at each page i intend to check the cookie ?